# TypeError in Python - Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I am doing web scraping of this page http://www.crmz.com/Directory/Industry806.htm, I am supposed to get all the

- #
- Company Name
- Country
- State/Province

But there is an rss link next to the compnay name so, I am not getting the result and showing a typeError.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

mech = Browser()
url = "http://www.crmz.com/Directory/Industry806.htm"
page = mech.open(url)

html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table", {"border":"0", "cellspacing":"1", "cellpadding":"2"})

rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
        print text+"|",
    print
```

and here is my output:

```
LRI$ python scrape.py

#| Company Name| Country| State/Province|
1.| 1300 Smiles Limited|

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 17, in <module>
    text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
TypeError
```

Comment: This is not the cause of the error, but you would be much better off if you used BeautifulSoup 4. BeautifulSoup 3 has been in legacy mode for 2 years now.

Comment: I reproduced the error with BeautifulSoup 3, your code works fine in BeautifulSoup 4 but can be vastly simplified.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have installed the buetifulsoup4 using this video tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKMslO6AuR8 but on running the program it is showing the same error –

Comment: As I said, it's not the cause of the exception, the error is because you used `.find()` instead of `.findAll()`, which is what my answer covers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception is caused by trying to join a `None` value for the text search:

```
>>> [td.find(text=True) for td in rows[6].findAll('td')]
[u'2.', u'1st Dental Laboratories Plc', None, u'United Kingdom', u'&nbsp;']
```

The `None` here is what triggers the exception:

```
>>> ''.join(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError
```

That's because `.find()` will only ever find the **first** text object, or return `None` if there is no such object. You probably meant to use `td.findAll(text=True)` instead, which will *always* return a list:

```
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        text = ''.join(td.findAll(text=True))
        print text+"|",
    print
```

or better still, use the `tag.getText()` method:

```
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    if cols:
        print u'|'.join([td.getText() for td in cols])
```

I'd strongly advice you to use BeautifulSoup 4 instead; BeautifulSoup 3 hasn't seen any bug fixes or other maintenance for over 2 years now.

You may also want to look into the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to write your output.

Answer (score -1):

you should replace

```
text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
```

with

```
text = ''.join(td.find(text="True"))
```

since the input of the `text` attribute is a string

Comment: `text=True` is the correct invocation; something else is wrong. `text=True` means: find all text objects in the `td` cell. It worked fine for the first result. Most likely `td` is `None`.

Comment: from beautifulsoap3 docs (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html): `s = soup.find(text='Heading')`. However you are right on the fact that Abu is not searching for "True" in the text.

Comment: From the same documentation: *`text` is an argument that lets you search for NavigableString objects instead of Tags. Its value can be a string, a regular expression, a list or dictionary, `True` or `None`, or a callable that takes a NavigableString object as its argument:*

Comment: Just to be explicit: **This is not sound advice**. `td.find(text=True)` is **the right way to find the first text object**. The problem is that the method returns *None* if no text object is present.

Comment: You are correct Martijn. My answer is wrong and I'm leaving it only because of your comments, that may be interesting for someone in the future.